# PHP for loop not increasing the incrementing variable $i

Tags: php

so it seems in PHP 7 something unusual is occurring, I was originally looping through an array using a foreach loop, however, that ceased to work, now I've decided to go with a for loop and have found that it just isn't increasing the incrementing $i variable, nor is the loop iterating.

Below is the code;

```
<?php
    $count = count($array);
        var_dump($count);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)  {
          echo $i;
          $v1 = ($array[$i][0] == $keys[0]);
          $v2 = ($array[$i][0] == $keys[1]);
          $v3 = ($array[$i][1] == $keys[0]);
          $v5 = ($array[$i][1] == $keys[1]);

            if($v1)
                return true;
            elseif($v2)
                return true;
            elseif($v3)
                return true;
            elseif($v5)
                return true;

        }
?>
```

In the live sample, $count is equal to 11, and the type of $array is an Array. $array and $keys are multidimensional arrays.

This code worked fine in PHP 5.4

Comment: Can you please share the `$array` and `$keys` Arrays?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the exact data in $array and $keys as this data is sensitive, I can share the schema;

Comment: $array = Array(0 => Array(0 => "", 1 => ""), 1 => Array(0 => "", 1 => ""))
$keys = Array(0 => "", 1 => "");

Where "" is a supplied STRING, FLOAT, DOUBLE, or INT.

Comment: the problem is not incrementing `$i`, the problem is that comparison is true at first loop, so the loop break. Manually compare `$array[0]` with `$keys` to see it

Comment: In the live data, that isn't correct. Please understand that the supplied amount here is no the live data.

Also, on VAR_DUMP for each $v variable, the results are Bool(false)

Comment: @SarahAllen I well know that yr example is not real data, but or the comparison is true, or your example is not complete and the problem is elsewhere. **Obviously,** `for` loop works even in php7: [Try-to-see](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/688af0fca5a0e0d5a8c8e59575993b6aeec69ad8)